# What does context mean in the webpack configuration?

Tags: webpack

I am a beginner user of webpack. I want to write a `webpack.config.js` to build my project. But something wrong with it!

Here is my `package.json` (All dependenciens are installed):

```
{
  "name": "webpack-101",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "dev": "webpack --progress --colors",
    "build": "webpack --progress --colors"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "css-loader": "^0.23.1",
    "style-loader": "^0.13.0",
    "webpack": "^1.12.14",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^1.14.1"
  }
}
```

And my project directory structure is:

```
--webpack-hello
---- dist
----src
    --css
      -- style.css
    --js
      -- entry.js
      -- content.js
---- index.html
---- package.json
---- webpack.config.js
---- node_modules
```

`entry.js` is:

```
// load css files
require("../css/style.css");

document.write("It works.");
document.write("<br/>");
document.write(require("./content.js"));
```

`style.css` is:

```
body {
    background: #f90;
}
```

The important file, `webpack.config.js` is :

```
var path = require('path');
var webpack = require('webpack');

module.exports = {
    context: __dirname + "/src",
    entry:  "./js/entry.js",
    output: {
        path: __dirname + "/dist",
        filename: "bundle.js"
    },
    module: {
        loaders: [{
            test: /\.css$/,
            loaders: ["style", "css"]
        }]
    }
};
```

When I run `npm run dev`, the console prints:

```
F:\my-workspace\codeTest\webpack\webpack-hello>npm run dev

> webpack-101@1.0.0 dev F:\my-workspace\codeTest\webpack\webpack-hello
> webpack --progress --colors

▀ ╢░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░
Hash: 081ea611fafd2241cf14
Version: webpack 1.12.14
Time: 107ms
    Asset     Size  Chunks             Chunk Names
bundle.js  3.03 kB       0  [emitted]  main
   [0] ./js/entry.js 194 bytes {0} [built]
   [2] ./js/content.js 93 bytes {0} [built]
    + 1 hidden modules

ERROR in ./css/style.css
Module not found: Error: Cannot resolve 'file' or 'directory' ./../../node_modules/css-loader/index.js in F:\my-workspace\codeTest\webpack\webpack-hello/src\css
 @ ./css/style.css 4:14-79

ERROR in ./css/style.css
Module not found: Error: Cannot resolve 'file' or 'directory' ./../../node_modules/style-loader/addStyles.js in F:\my-workspace\codeTest\webpack\webpack-hello/src\css
 @ ./css/style.css 7:13-71
▀ ╢░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░
```

If I modify the `webpack.config.js` (remove the `context`):

```
var path = require('path');
var webpack = require('webpack');

module.exports = {
    entry:  "./src/js/entry.js",
    output: {
        path: __dirname + "/dist",
        filename: "bundle.js"
    },
    module: {
        loaders: [{
            test: /\.css$/,
            loaders: ["style", "css"]
        }]
    }
};
```

It works well:

```
F:\my-workspace\codeTest\webpack\webpack-hello>npm run dev

> webpack-101@1.0.0 dev F:\my-workspace\codeTest\webpack\webpack-hello
> webpack --progress --colors

▀ ╢░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░
Hash: 798df3fe90bea39e31ad
Version: webpack 1.12.14
Time: 811ms
    Asset   Size  Chunks             Chunk Names
bundle.js  12 kB       0  [emitted]  main
   [0] ./src/js/entry.js 194 bytes {0} [built]
   [5] ./src/js/content.js 93 bytes {0} [built]
    + 4 hidden modules
▀ ╢░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░
```

I read the configuration of webpack, it says the `context` is : `The base directory (absolute path!) for resolving the entry option.`. But why I add it, the css files cannot reslove?

And what is the base practice for manage css files in webpack?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Most likely this is due to running webpack command (in your case: `npm run dev`)
in Windows environment.

Having this in the webpack.config.js (Windows environment):

`context: __dirname + "/src",`

is not good since you should use the \\ to seperate between folders.
Anyway **best practice** is to use the `path.resolve` which knows to append folders and sub folders using the correct slash (linux or windows)

The correct usage is (should work on Win or Linux):

```
const path = require('path');
const webpack = require('webpack');

module.exports = {
  context: path.resolve(__dirname, "src"),
  entry:  "./js/entry.js",
  output: {
    path: `${__dirname}/dist`,
    filename: 'bundle.js'
  }
};
```

Note: Seems that having the entry starts with `./` is important 
in the above example - 
(`entry: "./js/entry.js"`). Entry completes the context 
so it must start with `./` and not with `/` nor `"js/entry.js"` will not work as well.

Answer (score 1):

After I change `context` to this:

```
context: path(__dirname,'src/');
```

It runs as normal. I found out that `path` returns an absolute path.